# ubuntu 13.04 intallation guide

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, wubi

i am new to ubuntu operating system. i installed ubuntu 12.04.3 through wubi but it did'nt work perfectly it could not get wifi access while it was present and was working on windows 7. 2nd it could'nt displayed my 100GB partition like computer has not such partition

so i decided to install 13.04 i downloaded the 32 bit version, created bootable usb, after the main settings it took me to the screen where I had to decide the action.
but it said "replace windows 8" and "something else" first I have windows 7 not windows 8. 2nd after watching different tutorials I selected "something else" from the menu while I shrinked my 'C' drive and got 32GB space for ubuntu that I kept unallocated. that unallocated portion was shown with other partitions that while 'C' was separate only 2GB was free.

please first clear me this concept and the main thing is I want to install ubuntu on a separate drive besides 'C' such that if I ever encounter windows 7 problems and need to install a fresh copy of windows already installed ubuntu should not b effected of this formatted 'C' drive. totally ubuntu should have its own drive. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I will not go in detail about this since there are already too many resources online on this (what you're trying to do is setup a dual boot system) and I don't have much time.

In short, the "unallocated space" (formatting it will turn it into free space which will happen automatically during the installation) is the space that was created from shrinking the C partition. It is this space that you will need to select (during the Ubuntu installation). You can further partition this partition to / and /home (& maybe swap for suspending your system).

I didn't quite understand what you meant by

> that unallocated portion was shown with other partitions that while 'C' was separate only 2GB was free.

The "other drive" is called a partition; it's the one you created (unallocated). It lives next to C on the same drive.

As a resource refer to: http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/installing